# Is it possible to create function-local closures pre-C++11?

Tags: c++, function, closures, local, functor

With C++11, we get lambdas, and the possibility to create functions/functors/closures on-the-fly where we actually need them, not somewhere where they don't really belong.
In C++98/03, a nice way to make function-local functors/closures would've been the following:

```
struct{
  void operator()(int& item){ ++item; }
}foo_functor;
some_templated_func(some_args, foo_functor);
```

Sadly, you can't use local types for templates (Visual Studio allows this with language extensions enabled). My train of though then went the following way:

```
struct X{
  static void functor(int& item){ ++item; }
};
some_templated_func(some_args, &X::functor);
```

The obvious problem being, that you can't save any state, since local structs/classes can't have static members.
My next thought to solving that problem was using a mix of `std::bind1st` and `std::mem_fun` and non-static methods & variables, but unfortunately `std::mem_fun` somehow chokes with `std::mem_fn(&X::functor)`, which again might be because local struct/classes can't be used in templates:

```
// wanted, not working solution
struct X{
  int n_;
  X(int n) : n_(n) {}
  void functor(int& item) const { item += n_; }
};
X x(5);
some_templated_func(some_args,std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&X::functor),&x));
```

Fails under VC9 & VC10 (with `/Za`, disabled language extensions) with the following error

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::const_mem_fun1_t<_Result,_Ty,_Arg> std::mem_fun(_Result (_Ty::* )(_Arg) const)'
With the following template arguments:
'void'
'main::X'
'int &'
```

Or under gcc 4.3.4 with this error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘mem_fun(void (main()::X::*)(int&))’
```

Funnily enough, VC9 / VC10 still chokes on the above example, even with language extensions enables:

```
error C2535: 'void std::binder1st<_Fn2>::operator ()(int &) const' : member function already defined or declared
```

So, is the functionality stated in the title somehow, anyhow achievable? Or am I making a mistake in the last example in how I use `std::bind1st` or `std::mem_fun`?

Comment: `std::mem_fn(&X::functor)` chokes because `functor` isn't a member function, it's static.

Comment: @GMan: Nope, not in the last example.

Comment: @Xeo: Sorry I meant as an answer to "but unfortunately std::mem_fun somehow chokes...", in the second.

Comment: @Xeo: It has to be static, or else you end up with a pointer-to-member-of-local-type, which isn't a valid template argument.  Try `std::ptr_fun` instead, and use `bind_1st` to pass the actual captured values, not an instance of a local type.

Comment: @GMan: Ah, yeah, there should be a new paragraph and a double-colon, sorry.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Isn't `std::ptr_fun` for free functions?

Comment: @Xeo: For any function which is not a pointer-to-member.  Static functions are just like free functions, they form ordinary function pointers.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, but in my last example I have a member-function, so `std::ptr_fun` wouldn't be of use.

Comment: @Xeo: You'd use a static function, with state in bound parameters.  It would look much like what Potatoswatter has in his edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind1st` only works for binary functions, and in general it's very restricted. `mem_fn` works with non-static member functions only; for your application you would want `ptr_fun`.

Really the best tool for the job in C++03 is Boost Bind, or I'll demonstrate here with `tr1::bind` which is (in my opinion) more portable.

```
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;

int nums[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8 };

int main() {
    struct is_multiple {
        static bool fn( int mod, int num ) { return num % mod == 0; }
    };

    int *n = std::find_if( nums, nums + sizeof nums/sizeof*nums,
                        std::tr1::bind( is_multiple::fn, 3, _1 ) );

    std::cout << n - nums << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If it's a local class, how will you use it?  You can't pass it to any other function (except as a `void*`?).

Comment: That's the first example I brought up in the question, and you can't pass that functor to functions that are templated on a functor if it's a local class/struct. :|

Comment: @Ben: ah, I forgot about that! Actually I have used this idiom in a non-template context, but no that doesn't apply to OP's question.

Comment: @Xeo: Ah, now I understand your aim better, and why you wanted to use `bind1st`. Yes, `bind1st` should solve your problem, if you can make it work properly. The problem is that it's such a pain. I'll rework the answer a little.

Comment: The edited version very much looks like what I want. Too bad you need that whole binding stuff, but at least it lets you simulate function-local closures in a somewhat reasonable way. Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you'll have to implement one or more virtual methods declared in an interface.

```
template<typename Arg, typename Result>
struct my_unary_function
{
    virtual Result operator()(Arg) = 0;
};

template<typename Arg, typename Result>
struct my_unary_functor
{
    my_unary_function<Arg, Result> m_closure;
    my_unary_functor(my_unary_function<Arg, Result> closure) : m_closure(closure) {}
    Result operator()(Arg a) { return m_closure(a); }
};

template<typename T, TFunctor>
void some_templated_function( std::vector<T> items, TFunctor actor );
```

Then you can define and use a local closure:

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<int> collection;

    struct closure : my_unary_function<int, int>
    {
        int m_x, m_y;
        closure(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
        virtual int operator()(int i) const { cout << m_x + m_y*i << "\t"; return (m_x - m_y) * i; }
    };

    some_templated_function( collection, my_unary_functor<int,int>(closure(1, 5)) );
}
```

---

Credit to [@Omnifarious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167958/omnifarious) for this improvement (`my_unary_functor` not needed):

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<int> collection;

    struct closure : my_unary_function<int, int>
    {
        int m_x, m_y;
        closure(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
        virtual int operator()(int i) const { cout << m_x + m_y*i << "\t"; return (m_x - m_y) * i; }
    };

    // need a const reference here, to bind to a temporary
    const my_unary_functor<int,int>& closure_1_5 = my_unary_functor<int,int>(closure(1, 5))
    some_templated_function( collection, closure_1_5 );
}
```

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about, and that will work, but it's a bit ugly and slower. And yep, that was almost exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Ah, I see now. But this would need me to wrap every templated function I want to use in a new function which takes a `my_unary_function<Arg,Ret>`, correct?

Comment: @Xeo: The assumption is that the generic algorithm you're calling is already designed to use an interface.  If it's designed for a functor, it's not so nice, but I you could build a non-local functor/interface adapter class and then not need to wrap each function independently.

Comment: @Xeo: Not necessarily. You could create a temporary like this: `my_unary_function<int, int> &expr = closure(1, 5);` and then pass that temporary. It's type will be the right type and you won't have to have a special version of the template function to call.

Comment: @Omni: Ah, that's right. Yeah, that certainly solves the problem of writing wrapper functions. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed it, but I like @Omnifarious's fix better.  Because `my_unary_function<Arg,Result>` is not a local type, it CAN be used as the template function's type argument.

Comment: @Ben: This is a nice answer as it provides a real closure, but I'm gonna take @Potatoswatters answer, as it doesn't involve the whole virtual function stuff. Both look somewhat equally verbose though. ^^ Thanks.

Comment: @Xeo: Look beneath the surface and I think you'll find that `bind1st` works the same way, and `tr1::bind` is way more complicated.  Plus, `tr1::bind` will get very unwieldy very fast if you need to capture more than one argument.  Still, if it meets your needs, go for it.  Using a well-tested library is often preferable to writing new code.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, @Xeo: I suspect that `bind1st` does just as much dereferencing as the virtual function solution, it just happens in a different place. I actually suspect the virtual function version is slightly more efficient, but I might be wrong. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If this was doable in C++03, why would C++0x have introduced lambdas? There's a reason lambdas exist, and it's because binding and all the other C++03 solutions suck hideously.

Comment: Well, could be that C++0x just introduced a way easier solution. :)

Comment: For example, the ranged-for construct in C++0x is completely doable in C++03, but the ranged-for is so very much nicer.

Comment: The idea here is right but the reasoning is wrong. If it were doable we'd probably now how to fake it in C++03, but we don't. (Even if we could, though, C++0x still would have added the nicer syntax.)

Comment: @Omnifarious: The ranged-for loop is a hideous language construct, for plenty of reasons. @GMan: The Standard committee don't waste their time introducing solutions to non-problems. Well, ranged-for loop excluded.

Comment: @GMan: @Omnifarious and I do know how to fake it, but it's enough of a pain I think we usually end up making non-local functors.  C++0x doesn't make this possible, it makes it easier and more efficient. (Of course, it's not the addition of lambdas, but the allowance of local types as template arguments.  Lambdas make things easier yet.)

Comment: @DeadMG: Why is ranged-for such a hideous thing?