# transfer loop into C++03 for_each

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, foreach, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using bind1st for a method that takes argument by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822652/using-bind1st-for-a-method-that-takes-argument-by-reference)

I have the following traditional C++03 loop (using `auto` for stack overflow space efficiency only):

```
for (auto it = some_vector.begin(); it != some_vector.end(); ++it)
{
    foobar.method(*it);
}
```

In C++11, I managed to rewrite this into the following `for_each` invocation which works perfectly well:

```
std::for_each(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(),
              std::bind(&Foobar::method, std::ref(foobar), _1));
```

(Of course I could just use a lambda in C++11, but that's not the point.) Unfortunately, `std::bind` is not part of C++03, so I tried simulating it with `std::bind1st` and `std::mem_fun_ref`:

```
std::for_each(some_vector.begin(), some_vector.end(),
              std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref(&Foobar::method), std::ref(foobar)));
```

But this triggered a C2535 error in Visual Studio ("member function already defined or declared"):

```
// inside class binder1st in header xfunctional

result_type operator()(const argument_type& _Right) const
{   // apply functor to operands
    return (op(value, _Right));
}

result_type operator()(argument_type& _Right) const
{   // apply functor to operands   <--- ERROR C2535 HERE
    return (op(value, _Right));
}
```

Is this a const-correctness bug in Visual Studio, or have I done something wrong?

Also, `std::ref` does not seem to be part of C++03. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Even you cannot escape my edit-hammer!

Comment: `std::tr1::bind` is part of TR1 -- is that sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Might be of interest: [Is it possible to create function-local closures pre-C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723619/is-it-possible-to-create-function-local-closures-pre-c11).

Comment: @ildjarn I'm probably just going to keep the traditional loop for simplicity's sake. Just curious as to what exactly caused the error.

Comment: Also, any reason you don't want to use Boost? :)

Comment: As a note, can anyone explain me, _why_?! Given so pretty clear peace of code, TS finished with such a _mess_!

Comment: @Xeo: I have nothing against Boost. Sometimes I just go traditional for old time's sake and wonder why it doesn't work is all ;)

Comment: Is the error the same using `std::transform` rather than `std::for_each`?

Comment: GCC also rejects your `for_each`, so there's a good chance this isn't just a VS bug. Also your use of `auto` in the traditional loop is C++11, not C++03.

Comment: Ah, but a bit late I see you already explained that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use `std::mem_fun`? It expects a pointer as the first parameter, as such:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct foo{
    void method(int){}
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo f;
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&foo::method), &f));
}
```

Comment: +1 I proved it http://ideone.com/AAR4S